# Check if a string includes substring

Tags: google-apps-script, substring

This question will be explained by an example. I tried to use the includes command for this but this didn't work, you will see why in a second.

I've got 2 variables:

```
var Tutor = "Physics, English, History"; /* subjects that a tutor can teach */
var Learner = "Physics, History"; /* subjects in which a learner want to be tutored */
```

When I use the command:

```
var n = tutor.includes(Learner);
```

the outcome is "false" because of the order (I guess). However, I would like the outcome to be "true" because the Tutor's subjects include Physics and History. Sadly I can't change the order of the subjects nor delete the commas because this data is from a Google form.

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Do you want to see if words exist as a whole or just characters are exist in order (having some characters between each two character doesn't matter)

Comment: You need to break then into arrays. Would be smart to store them that way to begin with.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Do you want to achieve your question using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

It is way easier if you parse the data into arrays by splitting:

```
 const parse = data => data.split(", ");
```

Then you can just use `.every` and `.includes`:

```
 parse(Learner).every(learner => parse(Tutor).includes(learner)) // true
```

Comment: HI thx for the answer but I don't really get it, what would be the final code to put in my document?

Comment: Apps Script has no support for arrow function syntax.

Answer (score 0):

basically using `replace`, `split` and `every` you can get your desired result.

```js
var Tutor = "Physics, English, History";
var Learner = "Physics, History";

function checkIfContains(stringTocheck, stringToMatch) {
  //lets clean the spaces so we can have a better approach.
  const withoutSpaces = stringToMatch.replace(' ', '');
  const arrayFromString = withoutSpaces.split(',');

  //user EVERY to check that everything is included
  const result = arrayFromString.every(entry => stringTocheck.includes(entry))

  return result;

}

const contains = checkIfContains(Tutor, Learner);
console.log(contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the learner string an array by splitting it with a comma, 
 then loop through the newly created array with `every()` function, then check if  every word is present in the tutor
 string, if every word is present it will return true else false

```
 var Tutor = "Physics, English, History"; /* subjects that a 
  the tutor can teach */
 var Learner = "Physics, History"; /* subjects in wich a 
  learner want to be tutored */

  var learnerArray = Learner.split(',');
  let result = learnerArray.every( word => 
  Tutor.includes(word));

   console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow consist of more than working code. They should include explanations of what the solution is and why it works.

Comment: No it says it is missing a before statement on the line: let result = learnerArray.every( word =>

Comment: @AnanasTVTV i hope this answers your question, if it does please check it as the correct answer thanks

Comment: Apps Script doesn't currently support arrow functions, hence the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This goes beyond your question a little, but I think its the right direction. Both of your variables represent lists of subjects that I assume can vary. Therefore they would be better off as arrays of strings, rather than strings:

```
var Tutor = ["Physics", "English", "History"]; /* subjects that a tutor can teach */
var Learner = ["Physics", "History"]; /* subjects in which a learner want to be tutored */
```

Now you can check if the Tutor variable contains the same subjects as Learner, regardless of the order (which was your concern).

This can be done by looping through all the elements in Learner array and checking if the Tutor array contains them:

```js
function TutorContainsAllSubjects() {
  var Tutor = ["Physics", "English", "History"];
  var Learner = ["Physics", "History"];

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < Learner.length; i++) {
    if (!Tutor.includes(Learner[i])) {
      alert(false);
      return false;
    }
  }

  alert(true);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <button onclick="TutorContainsAllSubjects()">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic:

- assuming Tutor and Learner will always be a comma delimited list with possible spaces
- assuming also that the order of the items is not relevant
- remove spaces and then split on the comma
- then use **every** to determine if all entries are present.

```js
var Tutor = "Physics, English, History";
var Learner = "Physics, History";

function contains(csvList, csvSubList) {
    let aList = csvList.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
    let aSubList = csvSubList.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
    return aSubList.every( item => aList.includes(item) );
}

let result = contains(Tutor, Learner);
console.log( result );

// example of failure.
result = contains( Tutor, 'Physics, French' );
console.log( result );
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `indexOf()`, which returns the index position of the string you are looking for in the string you're looking in. If the substring isn't found, `indexOf()` returns `-1`.

```js
var Tutor = "Physics, English, History"; /* subjects that a tutor can teach */
var Learner = "Physics, History"; /* subjects in wich a learner want to be tutored */


var n = Tutor.indexOf(Learner) > -1;

console.log(n);
```

But, in your case, instead of doing string testing on potential string values that are separated by commas, it makes more sense to set up an array of subjects that are taught and then use `indexOf()` to search the array for a match:

```js
var subjects = ["Physics", "English", "History"];
var learner = ["Physics", "History", "Spanish"];

// Loop over the subjects the learner wants to learn
learner.forEach(function(subjectToLearn){
  // Check if the desired subject is taught
  if(subjects.indexOf(subjectToLearn) > -1){
     console.log(subjectToLearn + " is taught.");
  } else {
     console.log(subjectToLearn + " is not taught.");
  }
});
```

Comment: actually there is String.prototype.includes... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: `includes` is way more expressive than `indexOf`

Comment: Even if this is not "wrong" now, I still don't get why you are still recommending `indexOf` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Because there's no appreciable difference between it an includes. I personally don't find `indexOf` to be any less or more expressive than `includes`, so all things being equal, what's the problem?

Comment: @JonasWilms Ok, so you prefer it. But it doesn't explain why you *don't get* why someone would use another approach that does exactly the same thing with a different method.