# Add Notes Based on Criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I would like to set up a script for, which looks for specific criteria such as if a cell in a range contains something that is also in another column, or contains something specific.  My example sheet shows what I would like to happen: [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7QbllcsqjIdbfPB_rN96Bd5GQt2OkxNgggtAaJmz50/edit?usp=sharing) &
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXS5.jpg)

Anything in the name column (A) that contains the city name (B) as part of it would get a note ("Are you sure this is right?").  Ie if Row 1 has "Las Vegas Smith" as the name and "Las Vegas" as the city, it would get the note.    If Row 5 has "Charlotte Applegate" as the name and "Applegate" as the city, it would also get the note.

I also need to add a note to other cells in particular columns that meet criteria, but they are only looking at one column.  Ie anything that contains a hyphen in Column A would get a note like "Hyphen in the name?"

I have been able to highlight the name/city items using conditional formatting, using a custom formula `=REGEXMATCH (LOWER($A2),LOWER($B2))`.  And just using 'text contains' works for the rest for conditional formatting.  But I'd like to also add a note in addition to making them a different color.

I have found something to add notes,

```
function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Testing');
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A2:A5");
  var sourceCell = sheet.getRange("E2:E3");

  var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();

  targetCell.setNote(noteText);

}
```

(pointing to the second tab, Testing, which is just a copy of the first w/formatting removed.)  This results in the text from E2 as a note to every cell in the A2:A5 range.  I'm unsure how to add in that it needs to look for criteria and add the appropriate note based on that, and additionally that it needs to look for cells that *contain* that, not that match it exactly.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Thank you for providing a link to your sheet BUT your question should also stand on its own - that means you have to explain EXECTLY what you are trying to do _in_ the question.  Please don't expect that a user must open your spreadsheet to understand your question. In your case, as well as your spreadsheet, a screen snapshot or a data table might be enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: _but have not seen anything on how to check for particular characters/strings within a cell_ This is not an uncommon question. Refer [Check if a string includes substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54715390/1330560) (which has 6 answers) or [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/1330560) which has a more basic javascript approach.

Comment: Related question: [Add note based on value of another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75289226/1330560)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions linked in the comments didn't address my needs, but I did get help elsewhere creating code that would work as intended.  Additionally, it ignores any blanks rows.

```
function addNoteToCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columnARange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + numRows);
  var columnBRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + numRows);
  var columnAValues = columnARange.getValues();
  var columnBValues = columnBRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < columnAValues.length; i++) {
    if (columnAValues[i][0].length > 0 && columnBValues[i][0].length > 0) {
      if (columnAValues[i][0].indexOf(columnBValues[i][0]) != -1) {
        var cell = columnARange.getCell(i + 1, 1);
        cell.setNote("Are you sure this is right?");
      }
    }
  }
}
```